# How to create SQL view with dollar-quotes in Ansible?

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I have an sql file with following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION webapp.row_text_mappingtable(webapp.mappingtable) 
RETURNS text AS 
$$
SELECT coalesce($1.table_name::varchar, '') || ' ' ||
        coalesce($1.value::varchar, '') || ' ' ||
        coalesce($1.replacement::varchar, '') || ' ' ||
        coalesce($1.category::varchar, '');
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I can easily run this code in psql shell,  but I need to execute the view.sql file with this script using Ansible playbook. I have tried following code in playbook:

```
---
- name: file copy, move, downloading, etc.
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  become_user: postgres
  vars:
    project_path:  "{{ ansible_facts.env['PWD'] }}/.."
    db_owner: someowner
    db_password: somepass
    db_name: somedbname
    db_schema: somedbschema
  tasks: 

    - name: Apply sql scripts to create VIEWS in DB in schema "{{db_schema}}"
      community.general.postgresql_query:
        db: web_app_v2
        path_to_script: "/<somepath>/views.sql"
```

When I run this playbook - I get following error:

> fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Cannot execute SQL 'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION webapp.row_text_mappingtable(webapp.mappingtable) \nRETURNS text AS \n$$\nSELECT coalesce($1.table_name::varchar, '') || ' ' ||\n        coalesce($1.value::varchar, '') || ' ' ||\n        coalesce($1.replacement::varchar, '') || ' ' ||\n        coalesce($1.category::varchar, '')' None: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$\nSELECT coalesce($1.table_name::varchar, '') || ' ' ||\n        coalesce($1.value::varchar, '') || ' ' ||\n        coalesce($1.replacement::varchar, '') || ' ' ||\n        coalesce($1.category::varchar, '')"\nLINE 3: $$\n        ^\n, query list: ["CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION webapp.row_text_mappingtable(webapp.mappingtable) \nRETURNS text AS \n$$\nSELECT coalesce($1.table_name::varchar, '') || ' ' ||\n        coalesce($1.value::varchar, '') || ' ' ||\n        coalesce($1.replacement::varchar, '') || ' ' ||\n        coalesce($1.category::varchar, '')", '\n$$\nLANGUAGE plpgsql', '\n\n']"}

I have also tried to change each dollar symbol to single-quote and inner quotes to double singlequotes. But this not worked for me.

Please, help me to make Ansible execute this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use [community.general.postgresql_db](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/postgresql_db_module.html#ansible-collections-community-general-postgresql-db-module) with `state: "restore"` and `target: "/<somepath>/views.sql"`.